# NetBeans 8.1: shortcut to upload a single file

Tags: php, netbeans

I am trying to get the hang of netbeans for PHP development. Now I figured out how to set a connection (in run configuration) and when I use "upload files: on save" everything works fine. The problem is: I do not wish to automatically upload files. What I need is a shortcut to upload a file I'm working on when I'm ready.

So I went to Tools -> Options -> Keymap and set a new shortcut for "Upload...". The problem is: when I press the shortcut, it seems to re-connect. A constant connection seems to be only maintained with the "on save" feature.

Is there a way to handle this, to make sure that my upload... shortcut doesn't always open a new connection?

Thank you in advance!